# how to generate schema from a newline delimited JSON file in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to generate schema from a newline delimited JSON file, having each row in the JSON file has variable-key/value pairs. File size can vary from 5 MB to 25 MB.

**Sample Data:**

```
{"col1":1,"col2":"c2","col3":100.75}
{"col1":2,"col3":200.50}
{"col1":3,"col3":300.15,"col4":"2020-09-08"}
```

**Exptected Schema:**

```
[
  {"name": "col1", "type": "INTEGER"},
  {"name": "col2", "type": "STRING"},
  {"name": "col3", "type": "FLOAT"},
  {"name": "col4", "type": "DATE"}
]
```

> Notes: 
> There is no scope to use any tool, as files loaded into an inbound location dynamically. The code will use to trigger an event as-soon-as file arrives and perform schema comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is, that `json` does not have a date-type. So you will get `str` there.

What I would do, if I was you is this:

```py
import json

# Wherever your input comes from
inp = """{"col1":1,"col2":"c2","col3":100.75}
{"col1":2,"col3":200.50}
{"col1":3,"col3":300.15,"col4":"2020-09-08"}"""

schema = {}

# Split it at newlines
for line in inp.split('\n'):
    # each line contains a "dict"
    tmp = json.loads(line)
    for key in tmp:
        # if we have not seen the key before, add it
        if key not in schema:
            schema[key] = type(tmp[key])
        # otherwise check the type
        else:
            if schema[key] != type(tmp[key]):
                raise Exception("Schema mismatch")

# format however you like
out = []
for item in schema:
    out.append({"name": item, "type": schema[item].__name__})

print(json.dumps(out, indent=2))
```

I'm using python types for simplicity, but you can write your own function to get the type, e.g. if you want to check if a string is actually a date.

Comment: This is not giving me the expected output. The string is in date format !

Comment: This is the logic you need, just format the output the way you like. SO is not a code writing service, I'm just showing a possible solution to the "schema-finding problem".
And yes, the date is a `str` because `json` does not have a date format (as I stated) and everything between `"` is a `str` in python. It is just like that.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid multiple for loops. As file size can be up-to 25 MB and iterating line-by-line will be very expensive/time-consuming ?

Comment: You need to look at every entry in every line of the input to check it. So even if you use some magic to avoid the second loop, it will not improve the runtime complexity.

Comment: I updated the post showing how you can improve output formatting